# Module descriptors concept in redux-orm

Tags: redux, redux-orm

Found enough interesting library [Redux-orm](https://tommikaikkonen.github.io/redux-orm) for redux. Uses redux storage like database.

Who uses this library, please advice - what means `module descriptors` here?
With examples, please.

Because there is no detailed documentation and examples about it.

Thanks.

[Link for documentation](http://tommikaikkonen.github.io/redux-orm/module-descriptors.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm the current Redux-ORM maintainer.*

There's an amazing blog post series called [Practical Redux](https://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2016/10/practical-redux-part-0-introduction/) written by Mark Erikson where he gives a detailed introduction to Redux-ORM. It's a tiny bit outdated but still solid information. But our [Readme](https://github.com/tommikaikkonen/redux-orm/blob/master/README.md), mostly written by the original author Tommi Kaikkonen, is also a reliable (and more future-proof) source. We should definitely provide additional step-by-step documentation documentation on a dedicated site. That's mainly a manpower issue.

---

Your links refer to our JSDoc documentation which is automatically generated from our source code and comments in there. The `descriptors` module is an internal part of Redux-ORM that currently provides the code for relationship accessors. For instance, `author.books` would call the `backwardsManyToOneDescriptor` to resolve an author's books (if we assume that books can only be written by one author). You don't need to know how this works for using the library, though.

Comment: https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/updating-normalized-data#redux-orm - outdated version of code in example

Comment: @AlexanderLadonin Thank you, the docs you linked to are now up to date :)